# Is there a way to organize file content by list element in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project in python in regards to a file with information on students. The file  orders the students alphabetically by last name in the following format:

lastname,firstname,house,activity

the first direction was to change the format to

firstname,lastname,house,activity

I have done this. the next step is to organize them by house so that

```
Amewolo, bob J.,E2,none
Anderson, billy D.,E1,basketball
Andrade, Danny R.,E2,SOCCER
Banks-Audu, Rob A.,E2,FOOTBALL
Brads, Kev J.,N1,BAND
souza, Ian L.,E1,ECO CLUB
Dimijian, Annie A.,S2,SPEECH AND DEBATE
Garcia, Yellow,E1,NONE
Glasper, Larry L.,N1,CHOIR
```

will output them organized by house

```
Amewolo, bob J.,E2,none
Andrade, Danny R.,E2,SOCCER
Banks-Audu, Rob A.,E2,FOOTBALL
Anderson, billy D.,E1,basketball
souza, Ian L.,E1,ECO CLUB
Garcia, Yellow,E1,NONE
Brads, Kev J.,N1,BAND
Glasper, Larry L.,N1,CHOIR
Dimijian, Annie A.,S2,SPEECH AND DEBATE
```

Here is my code so far

```
def main():
    info = open('Studentinfo.txt', 'r')
    for i in info:
        data = i
        data = data.rstrip('\n')
        data = data.split(',')
        print(format(data[1], '19s'),end='')
        print(format(data[0], '19s'),end='')
        print(format(data[2], '19s'),end='')
        print(format(data[3], '19s'))

main()
```

should i use

```
data = data.sort(key = data[2])
```

or is there another way i can sort by that particular list element

Answer (score 1):

`.sort()` is in-place, so you just write:

```
data.sort(key=lambda item: item[2])
```

`lambda item: item[2]` is basically shorthand for:

```
def get_sort_key(item):
    return item[2]
```

Also, since your file is a CSV file, I'd use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `sort` with a `lambda` function as `key`:

```
with open('info.txt', 'r') as f:
      data = [line.split(',') for line in f]
print(sorted(lists, key=lambda x: x[2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a single item from the file. So if you sort that item, all you do is mix up the columns of a single item. For example `Brads, Kev J., N1, BAND` would be resorted to `BAND, Brads, Kev J., N1`.

What you want instead is have a list of *all* items and sort that list. So you need your data object for each item to another list, and sort that one:

```
allItems = []
for i in info:
    data = i.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    allItems.append(data)

allItems.sort(key=lambda x: x[2]) # sort by house

for data in allItems:
    print(format(data[1], '19s'), end='')
    print(format(data[0], '19s'), end='')
    print(format(data[2], '19s'), end='')
    print(format(data[3], '19s'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys # just used to print to sys.stdout, you can print to a file instead
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

with open('Studentinfo.txt') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f, ('lastname','firstname','house','activity'))
    w = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, ('firstname', 'lastname','house','activity'))
    w.writerows(sorted(r, key=itemgetter('house')))
```

---

```
 billy D.,Anderson,E1,basketball    
 Ian L.,souza,E1,ECO CLUB    
 Yellow,Garcia,E1,NONE    
 bob J.,Amewolo,E2,none    
 Danny R.,Andrade,E2,SOCCER    
 Rob A.,Banks-Audu,E2,FOOTBALL    
 Kev J.,Brads,N1,BAND    
 Larry L.,Glasper,N1,CHOIR    
 Annie A.,Dimijian,S2,SPEECH AND DEBATE
```