# Python only writing first line of file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I previously posted a question iregards to a program organizing information in a file:  [Is there a way to organize file content by list element in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072167/is-there-a-way-to-organize-file-content-by-list-element-in-python/16072228?noredirect=1#16072228)

I am now trying to write the information to a new file using the following code

```
def main():
    #open the file
    info = open('Studentinfo.txt', 'r')
    #make file content into a list
    allItems = []
    #loop to strip and split
    for i in info:
        data = i.rstrip('\n').split(',')
        allItems.append(data)

    allItems.sort(key=lambda x: x[3]) # sort by activity

    for data in allItems:
        first = data[1]
        last = data[0]
        house = data[2]
        activity = data[3]
        a = str(first)
        b = str(last)
        c = str(house)
        d = str(activity)
    f = open('activites.txt', 'w')
    f.write(a)
    f.write(b)
    f.write(c)
    f.write(d)
    f.close()

main()
```

however when i open the new text file instead of

```
Amewolo, bob J.,E2,none
Andrade, Danny R.,E2,SOCCER
Banks-Audu, Rob A.,E2,FOOTBALL
Anderson, billy D.,E1,basketball
souza, Ian L.,E1,ECO CLUB
Garcia, Yellow,E1,NONE
Brads, Kev J.,N1,BAND
Glasper, Larry L.,N1,CHOIR
Dimijian, Annie A.,S2,SPEECH AND DEBATE
```

there is only

```
 Amewolo, bob J.,E2,none
```

why does python only write the first line

Comment: You're missing indentation on the writes

Answer (score 5):

You are only writing to the file after the for loop instead of writing each set of data out one at a time.  In other words, you're iterating over all the data, then after that, you open the file, write the last 4 items, and then close it.

You need to open the file, write everything to it, and then close.  Try this

```
f = open('activites.txt', 'w') # open the file first
for data in allItems: # iterate over all of the data
    first = data[1]
    last = data[0]
    house = data[2]
    activity = data[3]
    a = str(first)
    b = str(last)
    c = str(house)
    d = str(activity)
    f.write(a) # write each element out
    f.write(b)
    f.write(c)
    f.write(d)
f.close() # then close
```

However, the `str()` calls are unnecessary.  `first`, `last`, `house`, and `activity` will already be strings.

combining with the `with` statement, this whole thing could collapse to

```
with open('activites.txt', 'w') as f:
    for data in allItems:
        data = [data[0], data[1]] + data[2:]
        print(*data, file=f, sep=', ')
```